# Can't acces FTP with Mono in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ftp, mono

I want to access to FTP with C# (Mono implementation - Stable .Net 3.5) in Unity 2017.1.2.p4.

For testing, i just try to access FTP and list directory.

```
public class FTPManager
{
    private string host = null;
    private string user = null;
    private string pass = null;

   public FTPManager(string hostIP, string userName, string password)
   {
        host = hostIP;
        user = userName;
        pass = password;
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += OnCertif;
   }

    public void Stop()
    {
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback -= OnCertif;
    }

    public void ListDirectory()
    {
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(host);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
        request.EnableSsl = true;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
        try
        {
            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            Debug.Log(string.Format("Directory List Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription));

            response.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.LogException(e);
        }
    }

    private bool OnCertif(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

But I always have the same error :

> Error : TlsException: The authentication or decryption has failed. Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.ProcessAlert (AlertLevel alertLevel, AlertDescription alertDesc)
>   Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.InternalReceiveRecordCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult) Rethrow as IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed.
>   Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.AsyncHandshakeCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult)

Looking for other post, I see that the authentication is Anonymous or mine is Normal.
Furthermore the FTP requires TLS protocol.

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem trying to access AWS lambda. 3.5 .Net simply doesn't support new tls protocol.

I've come to simplest way - just use Unity WWW object and it works pretty well